# Notepad++: I want to highlight questions in multiple colors?

Tags: fonts, formatting, notepad++, syntax-highlighting, highlighting

I've written a script in Notepad++, and I want to highlight individual lines based on who is speaking.  I'm just trying to find a place where I can change text color or background color for individual lines.  Is there anything built into Notepad++ that does that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current solution I'm using:

1. Drop-down: `View->User Defined Languages`
2. Create keyword (character's indicator).
3. Change the background color.

It highlight's the character's name in other places in the text, though.  An undesired but unobtrusive side-effect.  No highlight feature I can find, unfortunately.

Comment: Essential reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761206/notepad-user-defined-regions-with-folding

Answer (score 0):

1.Select the text you want to highlight

2. Right click on it
3. Go to 'Style Token' and select any style

Comment: The OP wants to highlight the *entire* text (or at least a large portion of it) but in several different colors. Can you explain how they can use your suggestion? … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: It's true, that's what I wanted to do; however, this is very relevant and useful, and I will surely come back here and use this answer as a reference.  Appreciate it, Vishal.